# Conjectured values for infinite products?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, infinite-product, open-problem

When I look at simple open problems in calculus ( not including analytic Number theory mainly ) most conjectures are , or are equivalent to , infinite sums or integrals being equal to a closed form real number.

So I wonder about  famous open problems where we have the conjecture that an infinite product is equal to a closed form real number $>0$. 
No dirichlet series written as product allowed.

Comment: A sum being equal to a given number may be translated to a product being equal to a given number using the exponential map, and we may translate back again using logarithms. I just think that many prefer sums of logarithms to products. See, for instance, the Stirling approximation, which approximates $n! = \prod k$, but is actually proven by approximating $\sum \ln(k)$.

Comment: The Riemann hypothesis is  $\prod_\rho (1-\frac{2}{1/2+i \Im(\rho)}) = \frac{\pi}{6}$